# Text generation algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm or some advices to implement it.
Input:

```
"{1|2} word {3|4}"
```

Output:

```
["1 word 3", "1 word 4", "2 word 3", "2 word 4"]
```

Also, i want to support nested constructions - `"{1|2{0|1}}" -> ["1", "20", "21"]`
I realize that the question is too general, but don't want to implement the wheel. Maybe you saw similar things.

**UPD**

```
from pyparsing import *
from collections import deque

s = u"{1|2} {3|4}"

deque = deque()

def mesh_lists(listOne, listTwo):
    result = []
    for l1 in listOne:
        for l2 in listTwo:
            firstWord = str(l1).strip()
            secondWord = str(l2).strip()
            result.append(" " + firstWord + " " + l2 + " ")
    return result

def action(string, pos, token):
    global deque
    deque.append(list(token[0]))

def processDeque():
    global deque
    while len(deque) > 1:
        l1 = deque.popleft()
        l2 = deque.popleft()
        res = mesh_lists(l1,l2)
        deque.appendleft(res)
    return [x.strip() for x in deque[0]]

_lcurl = Suppress('{')
_rcurl = Suppress('}')
_pipe = Suppress('|')
word = Regex("[^{|}]+")
varBlock = Forward()
entry = word | varBlock
varList = Group(entry + ZeroOrMore(_pipe + entry))
varBlock << (_lcurl + Optional(varList) + _rcurl).setParseAction(action)
template = ZeroOrMore(entry)

res = template.parseString(s)
print processDeque()
```

It supports only "{||}{||}" constructions. No barewords, no nested constructions.

Comment: If the question is too general, it's likely to be closed.  Try to gather your thoughts and attempts together and show us what you've come up with.  Although I've seen this sort of problem in Theory of Computation books before - the general idea is you have some token in your alphabet sandwiching an unchanging token.

Answer (score 4):

This project looks suitable for you: https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex

> Exrex is a tool that generates all matching strings to a given regular
>   expression.

Answer (score 0):

The pyparsing published examples include a regex inverter.